# Cannot select text in an input box

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML/CSS for float labels on a form (sorry if it's a bit messy)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font: 14px/1.4 Sans-Serif;
}

form {
  width: 320px;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}

form>div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

form input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  background: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 4px 0 4px 0px
}

form input:valid+label {
  top: -7%;
  z-index: 100;
  font-size: 70%;
  padding: 1px 6px;
}

input:valid+label>div {
  padding: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

form label {
  transition: background 0.2s, color 0.2s, top 0.2s, bottom 0.2s, right 0.2s, left 0.2s;
  position: absolute;
  color: #999;
  padding: 7px 6px;
}

form.test-form input {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}

form.test-form label {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

form.test-form input:focus+label {
  top: -7%;
  z-index: 100;
  font-size: 70%;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.label {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: padding 0.2s;
}

form.test-form input:focus+label>div {
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Test Form</h1>
  <form class="test-form">
    <div>
      <input id="name" name="name" type="text" required>
      <label for="name">
        <div class="label">
          <span class="text">Your Name</span>
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

This is working exactly how I need it to. The only issue is that I cannot select the text in the input box after it is entered (if you try it you will notice that "YOUR NAME" is highlighted before the actual text in the input box is).

I am assuming this has something to do with the way I am setting the `z-index`... is there a way to edit the z-index for only the text in an input box? If not, is there an obvious solution to fix this issue?

Comment: It works fine in Firefox 72, text is highlighting fine.

Comment: I found another issue - when you type something in the inputbox, you can't select text with mouse. Because the label <YOUR NAME> covers input box.

Comment: <label for="name"> - height must be like this height: fit-content;

Comment: @jordan What does `highlight` mean?

Comment: @O.o by highlight i mean to select text. The issue you are describing is the same one I am trying to solve! sorry for being unclear

Comment: @jordansandberg you can edit the job posting for future conflict.

Comment: @Triby I cannot select the text properly in Firefox 72.0.2. If I click the textbox border, the entire inputted text is selected, but that's not proper functionality for textbox text selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try This:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font: 14px/1.4 Sans-Serif;
}

form {
  width: 320px;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}

form>div {
  position: relative;
  
}

form input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  background: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 4px 0 4px 0px
}


form input:valid+label { /*<--Changed*/
  top: -55px;
  left:10px;
  z-index: 100;
  font-size: 70%;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  position:relative;
}

input:valid+label>div {
  padding: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

form label {
  transition: background 0.2s, color 0.2s, top 0.2s, bottom 0.2s, right 0.2s, left 0.2s;
  position: absolute;
  color: #999;
  padding: 7px 6px;
}

form.test-form input {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}

form.test-form label {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background:#FFF;
}

form.test-form input:focus+label {  /*<--Changed*/
  top:-55px;
  left:10px;
  font-size: 70%;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.label {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: padding 0.2s;
}

form.test-form input:focus+label>div {
  padding: 2px;
}

#name:focus {  /*<--Added*/
  z-index:1000;
}

#name:focus + label {  /*<--Added*/
 position:relative;
 z-index:1001;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Test Form</h1>
  <form class="test-form">
    <div>
     <input id="name" name="name" type="text" required>
      <label for="name">
        <div class="label">
          <span class="text">Your Name</span>
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: This works great, thank you! I'm not 100% sure why your solution works though. Was it an issue with the z-index?

Comment: Also, the transition of the label is behaving strange. Try slowing the transition speeds down to 3s and clicking on the input box

Comment: @Ehsan can you explain the fix your have done here?

Answer (score 0):

I hade a same issue. After a lot of research I found that, set "::selection" and
"::-moz-selection" globaly To avoid double-click highlight issues on some of my components. This, of course, would have an effect on the inputs. Now that I've excluded input components, everything is back to normal.