# CSS unable to select the text in the website

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-selectors

I got assigned to a React front-end project written in micro front-end architecture.
And the problem with this application is users can't select the text by simply mouse also on text boxes, and text areas users can't select what they have typed so easily.

I have noticed the following things in this project.

1. They have used a lot of CSS positioning methods like absolute, and
   relative.
2. They have used z-index in so many places as well.
3. And the selecting issue is happening in the Chrome browser and works fine in the Firefox browser. (In firefox you can select text without any issue.)

I tried to solve this problem by following approaches,

1. First I commented on all the z-indices and try. I thought an overlay of something blocked the selection.
2. After that I noticed there is another way to block the select selection and I found this `user-select` related CSS in this project as well. I commented on all of them and tried again. (**At the early stage of this project they may want this behavior, that's why I see this user-select**)

```css
-webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
 -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10 and IE 11 */
 user-select: none; /* Standard syntax */
```

But still, both of these aren't solving the problem. What are the other possible scenarios this error could occur? It is really hard to debug, cause in Chrome dev tools, it won't show all the inherited CSS for a given element. (For example, if I select a `<p>` tag it won't show any user-select: none properties even though it is applied at a global level.)

Hope my question is clear to you.
Any help Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try and locate the CSS under the [`computed css`](https://docs.joomlabamboo.com/getting-started/how-to-use-the-computed-panel-in-the-chrome-inspector.html) tab?

Comment: We can't debug your code at this stage because you did not provide any reproducible example of your current issue.

Comment: @SMAKSS I can't re-create this issue by myself. But this is something similar to my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59850686/cannot-select-text-in-an-input-box

Comment: @DarkBee Yes I checked both

Answer (score 0):

If `user-select: none;` is really not the reason behind this, then you can try one of the following:

1. Either add a `z-index: 1000;` to the element from which you want to
   select the text
2. Otherwise, try to disable you JS on the website (they may be a
   function preventing users from selecting text).

As long as I do not have any code snippet, I cannot give further info.